# Clickin issue in Flash and XML

Tags: xml, dynamic, actionscript-2, flash-cs3

I have the php backend that displays an xml page with data for flash consuming.

Flash takes it and creates a textfields dynamicaly based on this information.

I have a few items in menu on top and when I click one of them, data is taken from php and everything is displayed in scroll in flash.

The problem is that if I click too fast between menu items, then I get buggy layout.

The text (only the text) is becoming part of the layout and is displayed no metter what item in menu I am currently in and only refreshing the page helps.

```
    var myXML:XML = new XML();
myXML.ignoreWhite=true;

myXML.load("/getBud1.php");

myXML.onLoad = function(success){

if (success){

var myNode = this.firstChild.childNodes;

    var myTxt:Array = Array(0);

      for (var i:Number = 0; i<myNode.length; i++) {

          myTxt[i] = "text"+i+"content";

    createTextField(myTxt[i],i+1,65,3.5,150, 20);

    var pole = eval(myTxt[i]);

          pole.embedFonts = true;

          var styl:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

          styl.font = "ArialFont";

          pole.setNewTextFormat(styl);

          pole.text = String(myNode[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue);

          pole.wordWrap = true;

            pole.autoSize = "left";

            if(i > 0) {

            var a:Number = eval(myTxt[i-1])._height + eval(myTxt[i-1])._y + 3;

            pole._y = a;
            } 
            attachMovie("kropka2", "test"+i+"th", i+1000);

            eval("test"+i+"th")._y = pole._y + 5;

            eval("test"+i+"th")._x = 52;

      } 
}
}
```

I tried to load the info and ceate text fields from top frame and then refer to correct place by instance names string e.g. budData.dataHolder.holder.createTextField , but then when I change between items in menu the text dissapears completely untill I refresh the page.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved... I created raw as2 code and whenever I loaded data from XML, the variables were initialized later than the reading from them part. I wrapped everything into the function and loaded xml data on 1st frame into the array, then I read data from another function and it works.